# Convert list with NULL entres to data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a list named `z` :

```
z<-list( list(a=1, b=2),  list(a=2, b=3), list(a=NULL, b=4))
```

I want this to be converted to a data.frame with the corresponding `a` entry in the `data.frame` assigned as `NULL`. 
Doing this,

```
do.call( rbind, lapply( z, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=TRUE ) )
```

as expected, gives this error:

```
 Error in data.frame(a = NULL, b = 4, check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

What is the work around?

Comment: What exactly is a `NULL` value in your data? You sure you're not looking for `NA`?

Comment: Yes, I realize it would make equal sense to replace `NULL` with `NA`. 'NULL' values are those that are present in a SQL table entry.

Comment: @Enigman, probably you should accept the answer (since it's working) and mark this closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind, z))
     a b
1    1 2
2    2 3
3 NULL 4
```

Comment: @Enigman, right--it appears not. If you view the `str` of the object created with this answer, both `a` and `b` are `list`s.

Comment: Not gonna lie, data.frame of lists (list of lists) is super interesting data structure. If you do it with a named list of lists that are themselves named, you will be able to do df$column$row. And then assign whatever to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, z))
     a b
1    1 2
2    2 3
3 NULL 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in data frame of numeric values instead of data frame of lists, you can try the below.

```
lz <- lapply(z, function(x) {
    nonnull <- sapply(x, typeof)!="NULL"
    do.call(data.frame, c(x[nonnull], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
})

require(plyr)
df <- ldply(lz)
```

Note that the result will have `NULL`s converted to `NA`s to form valid dataframes.

```
> df
   a b
1  1 2
2  2 3
3 NA 4
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 NA
 $ b: num  2 3 4
```