# Converting an R list with NULL sub-elements to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a list below

```
> str(lll)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ Name : chr "Sghokbt"
  ..$ Title: NULL
  ..$ Value: int 7
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ Name : chr "Sgnglio"
  ..$ Title: chr "Mr"
  ..$ Value: num 5
```

How can I convert this list to a data frame as below?

```
> df
     Name Title Value
1 Sghokbt  <NA>     7
2 Sgnglio    Mr     5
```

`as.data.frame` doesn't work, I suspect due to the `NULL` in the first list element. **EDIT:** I have also tried `do.call(rbind, list)` as suggested in another question, but the result is a matrix of lists, not a data frame.

To reproduce the list:

```
list(structure(list(Name = "Sghokbt", Title = NULL, Value = 7L), .Names = c("Name", 
"Title", "Value")), structure(list(Name = "Sgnglio", Title = "Mr", 
    Value = 5), .Names = c("Name", "Title", "Value")))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list with NULL entres to data.frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388096/convert-list-with-null-entres-to-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Sort of, but the other question's answers are not what I'm looking for. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: you can do : `do.call("rbind", lapply(lll, function(x){x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA; unlist(x)}))` but it gives a matrix so you have other manipulations to do to put back `value` in numeric, and also, its quite ugly ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution myself.

My approach is to first convert all the sub-lists into dataframes, so I have a list of dataframes instead of list of lists. These dataframes will just drop the `NULL` variables.

```
ldf <- lapply(lll, function(x) {
  nonnull <- sapply(x, typeof)!="NULL"  # find all NULLs to omit
  do.call(data.frame, c(x[nonnull], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
})
```

The resultant list of dataframes:

```
> str(ldf)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Name : chr "Sghokbt"
  ..$ Value: int 7
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Name : chr "Sgnglio"
  ..$ Title: chr "Mr"
  ..$ Value: num 5
```

From here I get a little help from `plyr`.

```
require(plyr)
df <- ldply(ldf)
```

The result has the columns out of order, but I'm happy enough with it.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Name : chr  "Sghokbt" "Sgnglio"
 $ Value: num  7 5
 $ Title: chr  NA "Mr"
```

I won't accept this as an answer yet for now in case there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Tidyverse solution

Here's a solution with the tidyverse which might be more readable  or at least more intuitive to read for those who are familiar with dplyr and purrr.

```
lll %>%
  # apply to the whole list, and then convert into a tibble
  map_df(~
           # convert every list element to a char vector
           as.character(.x) %>%
           # convert the char vector to a tibble row
           as_tibble_row(.name_repair = "unique")) %>%
  # convert all "NULL" entries to NA
  na_if("NULL") %>%
  # set tibble names assuming all list entries contain the same names
  set_names(lll[[1]] %>% names())
```

##### There are several tricks to note:

1. `map_df` cannot merge the character vectors into a dataframe. therefore, you convert them into dataframe rows by `as_tibble_row()`. theoretically, you could name these vectors but `as.character` has no names attribute, but you need a conversion into a *named* vector
2. for `as_tibble_row()`, you need to specify a `.name_repair` argument, so `map_df` can merge the tibble rows without names
3. i'm truly grateful for the `dplyr::na_if()` function, you should be too!
4. `lll[[1]] %>% names()` is just one way to get the names of the first list entry, and it assumes the other list entries are named the same and in the same order. you should check that before.

##### Details:

when you use `na_if()`, you so elegantly replace this code by Ricky (which is totally fine but hard to remember):

```
ldf <- lapply(lll, function(x) {
  nonnull <- sapply(x, typeof)!="NULL"  # find all NULLs to omit
  do.call(data.frame, c(x[nonnull], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lll))
     Name Title Value
1 Sghokbt  NULL     7
2 Sgnglio    Mr     5
```

`do.call` is useful in that it accepts lists as an argument. It will execute the function `rbind` which combines the lists observation by observation. `data.frame` structures the output as needed. The weakness is that because data frames also accept lists, the new object will keep the list attributes and will be difficult to perform calculations on the elements. Below, is another option, but also potentially problematic.

By removing the NULL value first:

```
null.remove <- function(lst) {
  lapply(lst, function(x) {x <- paste(x, ""); x})
}

newlist <- lapply(lll, null.remove)
asvec <- unlist(newlist)
col.length <- length(newlist[[1]])
data.frame(rbind(asvec[1:col.length], 
                 asvec[(col.length+1):length(asvec)]))
      Name Title Value
1 Sghokbt           7 
2 Sgnglio    Mr     5 

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Name : Factor w/ 2 levels "Sghokbt ","Sgnglio ": 1 2
 $ Title: Factor w/ 2 levels " ","Mr ": 1 2
 $ Value: Factor w/ 2 levels "5 ","7 ": 2 1
```

This method coerces a value onto the NULL elements in the list by pasting a space onto the existing object. Next `unlist` allows the list elements to be treated as a named vector. `col.length` takes note of how many variables there are for use in the new data frame. The last function call creates the data frame by using the `col.length` value to split the vector.

This is still an intermediate result. Before regular data frame operations can be done, the extra space will have to be trimmed off of the factors. The digits must also be coerced to the class `numeric`.

I can continue the process when I have another chance to update.

Comment: Yeah, only that it's not a `data.frame`. Try `str(do.call(rbind, lll))`

Comment: I wanted to leave a little bit for them to work at the end :). updated

Comment: Try `str(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lll)))`

Comment: `'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:` There's some list-y language in it though. Will this behave oddly in calculations?

Comment: @KevinBrown I'm adding more, and another possible method.

Comment: It doesn't work @CathG. Note the comment by @Ananda, the answerer. `''data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Name :List of 2` It looks like a data frame but is simply a list of lists.

Comment: thanks for the effort on this @plafort.

I think `null.remove` in the `lapply` can simply be replaced by `paste0` and it will produce similar result (minus the extra space).

You are right that this is not fully what I want (because of the lost `class` information due to coercion), but thanks nonetheless. It rather surprises me that there is no simple way to do this.