# How to transform a list into a lookup table

Tags: r, list, lookup-tables

I have a list output that looks like this snippet:

```
[[1]]
[1] 109

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 80
```

Is there a way to transform it into this format?

```
C1   C2
1    109
2    0 (or NA)
3    80
```

Not sure where to even start... If I unlist it I noticed that I lose my integer(0) positions, which are important for me to keep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388096/convert-list-with-null-entres-to-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `as.numeric` you can retain `integer(0)` as `NA`.

```
data.frame(C1 = seq(length(lst)), C2 = as.numeric(lst))

#  C1  C2
#1  1 109
#2  2  NA
#3  3  80
```

Comment: Also `seq_along(lst)`.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of

```
L = list(109,integer(0),80)
sapply(L, '[', 1:1) #OR sapply(L, function(a) a[1])
#[1] 109  NA  80

#If you need a data.frame

data.frame(cbind(1:length(L),lapply(L, '[', 1:1)))
#  X1  X2
#1  1 109
#2  2  NA
#3  3  80
```

Comment: that gets me through!

Comment: I'm not familiar wiht the '[' can you explain? I'm assuming the 1:1 just references the first element in each list.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19261054/7128934) is a great explanation

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `stack`

```
stack(setNames(lapply(lst, `length<-`, 1), seq_along(lst)))[2:1]
```